# Brew Hack - What Can I Make with These Ingredients?

Tags: beer, experiments, small-batch

I have some leftover ingredients that are just going to go bad as I won't be making any brew for awhile.

**What I have:**

- ~1 lb Carafa III crushed malted barley
- Several Packets of Dry Champagne Yeast
- 1/2 ounce aroma Hops (pellets @ 3.8%)

I'd like to mix these up and ferment something, really, just for an experiment.  I have 1 gallon glass fermenters, so I can easily make a small batch.

Will this work, any tips on how I should do it, or should I just throw the ingredients away because it won't be worth it?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**  I used the ingredients along with Honey to produce a beverage similar to Braggot.  Ultimately, the beverage turned out awful on top and beautiful underneath.  Because I only brewed a gallon, and used the entire pound of Carafa, the drink was much too harsh, as it was overpowered by the burnt, dark malt flavors.  Underneath, however, was a smooth and light beverage.  Had I used only a few ounces of the malt, this drink would have been a delight.  Lessons learned.

Comment: Are you willing to buy anything? Like a pound of malt extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will be unlikely to get any conversion out of the Carafa as it has been kilned to the point that all of the enzymes have been destroyed. Weyermann shows that this malt has No Enzymatic Power http://www.weyermann.de/usa/bmprodukte_neu.asp?idkat=204&umenue=yes&idmenue=269&sprache=10

If you were to add some base malt (or DME and steep the Carafa) you may be able to make a very dry brown ale of some sort I suppose.

Comment: Got it...What about using the carafa for flavor and color and adding a different sugar source, such as molasses or brown sugar?

Comment: this might work, you might also consider honey which would generally make this into a Braggot http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead#Mead_variants where the Dry Champagne Yeast would be a bit more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it all up tightly and put it in the freezer.